# postscript get and put commands

Tags: get, stack, put, postscript

How and what format do the "get" and "put" commands in postscript work?
When I see something like this I feel there are too many operand and not enough operators.

```
    /x exch def
    /temp x x length 1 sub get def
```

Answer (score 2):

put and get only work with composite objects such as arrays and dictionaries. You should get hold of the PostScript Language Reference Manual for details on what operands are expected for each operator.

This and other documents can be found from the [Postscript tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postscript/info).